# Angularjs 1.3 async filter not working

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have following code, which basically loads messages from the server via $http.get request in the service and then used in the i18n filter. Filter was working fine with angular version 1.2.24 but after updating to 1.3.5 it no longer works.

I was wondering if anyone ran into similar issue and can shine some light on this.

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('MessageFactory', function ($http, $locale, $log) {
    var messages = {};

    $http.get("/i18n/" + $locale.id + "/list", {cache: true}).success(function(data) {
        $log.debug("Getting messages for", $locale.id);
        messages = data;
    });

    return {
        getMessage: function (key) {
            return messages[key];
        }
    }
})

.filter('i18n', function (MessageFactory) {
    return function (key) {
        return MessageFactory.getMessage(key);
    }
});
```

Html Code

```
<h2>{{'message.page.title'|i18n}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally after couple of hours of digging I changed

```
.filter('i18n', function (MessageFactory) {
    return function (key) {
        return MessageFactory.getMessage(key);
    }
});
```

to

```
.filter('i18n', function (MessageFactory) {
    function filterFn(key) {
        return MessageFactory.getMessage(key);
    }

    filterFn.$stateful = true;

    return filterFn;
});
```

Notice **filterFn.$stateful** that's what did the trick.

Comment: didn't knew this, nice.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find docs proof of that, but it looks like angular 1.3.x executes code inside modules only when it firstly used, and <= 1.2.x do it when app started.

Looks like you need to change your code to load locale files in `app.run()` method;

Something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vELogx

Comment: Tried that, the problem with the "run" approach is that the exception is thrown inside MessageFacotry.getMessage while messages is null. As soon as data from the $http.get is returned the filter works as expected.